# "I'm my own grandpa" – is there a word for this?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I was listening to a [Chad Morgan](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlJ26ElFrr4) record today, on which his cover of the song [*I'm my own grandpa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_My_Own_Grandpa) features as the first track.

[The lyrics](http://mudcat.org/@displaysong.cfm?SongID=2991) of the song describe a bizzare, but plausible scenario, in which a man finds himself becoming his own grandfather through an unfortunate combination of marriages. (The narrator marries a widow, whose adult daughter then ends up marrying his father.)

Thinking back on the times that I've heard one person mock another by suggesting that their lineage contains such an anomaly, this was always done by stating the specific relationships. For instance, the person would say something along the lines of "I bet [this person]'s brother is his uncle".

That made me wonder... Has there ever been an actual word to describe the state of being related to yourself as a result of a marriage?

Comment: Philip J. Fry. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest **kin to self**.

*Kin* refers to [one's related people](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kin), and is often used to describe family relatonships in academic contexts.

I don't know of an existing single word that conveys the same meaning. Maybe *self-kin*? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I never heard, read, or came across anything, any word, any term for this state. I also searched and found nothing. For example, see [WolframAlaph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=relationships) (the Computational Search Engine) and you often see or search for the **genealogy description**, not **a single term**.

Also you can take a look at these pages:

1. [Genealogy Relationships](http://www.searchforancestors.com/utility/relationshipterms.html)
2. [What are relations?](http://www.genealogy.com/16_cousn.html)

Answer (score 2):

**consanguine** (or **consanguineous**) is the closest I can come up. It’s an adjective meaning “of the same blood line”, “descending from the same ancestor”. Derivatives include *consanguineal* (adj.) and *consanguinity* (noun). A marriage with one close to yourself in your blood line is called **consangineous marriage**.

All that is about blood line. I don’t think (and couldn't find) an similar term for the formal relationship of marriage, as the one you’re looking for, except for the first degree (called ***“in-law”***). My husband’s brothers are my brothers-in-law, but that doesn’t extend to the rest of the “network” formed by marital bonds.

Comment: Ironically in this example, though, you're not of the same blood line as your 'grandmother'.  This becoming your own grandpa thing can only happen 'in law'.

Comment: @Jez: of course, sorry it wasn’t clear enough. I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

If you were actually your own grandfather, I am assuming through time travel or some other plot device, then you would be autoprogenitive. As for being your own in-law, not aware of a specialized word.